# From DataFrame to Excel using JupyterNotebook

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

Hi i have this sample data from dataFrame to excel. Now i want to add new columns. My problem is im new to JupyterNotebook and im learning. Here is my code below.

```
import pandas as pd
import sys
print('Python version ' + sys.version)
print('Pandas version ' + pd.__version__)

# Create DataFrame
d = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
e = [10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]
df = pd.DataFrame(d, columns = ['Number'])
df
```

output is this one:

```
   Number
0   1
1   2
2   3
3   4
4   5
5   6
6   7
7   8
8   9
```

now I've added a new column data which is column e. How will i add new Columns to it?

Comment: This isn't a Jupyter question... Where in the Pandas documentation is unclear about Excel functions or adding columns?

Comment: How do you intend to hold 2 series of unequal length (d = 9, e = 6) in a single dataframe?

Comment: ive just seen this existing code and try to execute on it in my Notebook

Comment: All I'm saying is that Pandas is the documentation you should be looking at, not Jupyter

Answer (score 0):

The shape of d and e, is not same. The way of add, I don't how to do. Maybe this way?

```
In [83]: import pandas as pd

In [84]: d = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

In [85]: e = [10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]

In [86]: df = pd.DataFrame(d, columns = ['Number'])

In [87]: dfe = pd.DataFrame(e, columns=["e"])

In [88]: pd.concat([df, dfe], axis=1)
Out[88]:
   Number     e
0       1  10.0
1       2  11.0
2       3  12.0
3       4  13.0
4       5  14.0
5       6  15.0
6       7   NaN
7       8   NaN
8       9   NaN

In [89]: pd.concat([df, dfe], axis=1, join="inner")
    ...:
Out[89]:
   Number   e
0       1  10
1       2  11
2       3  12
3       4  13
4       5  14
5       6  15
```